# How do we prevent the labels in a repeater from being overwritten?

Tags: asp.net

I use a repeater control to display data in which three items are bound during the ItemDataBound event the problem with the code is that the last record is displayed in all the rows of the repeater overwritng the already existing values, how do i stop this? I use code like this

### *.aspx.cs code*

```
DataSet dsJobCardHistory =new DataSet();
double dcPriceIncl;
double dcPriceExcl; 
double dcTax;

protected void Job_History()
{ 
   dsJobCardHistory = objReportManager.Get_JobCard_History(strCustNo, strTranId);
}

protected void repJobCard_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

  for (int i = 0; i < dsJobCardHistory.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++)

   {
     dcPriceIncl = Convert.ToDouble(dsJobCardHistory.Tables[0].Rows[i][6].ToString());
     dcTax = dcPriceIncl * 0.14;
     dcPriceExcl = dcPriceIncl - dcTax;

      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType==
                                ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
       {
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblRepPrice")).Text = 
             Convert.ToString(dcPriceExcl);
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblRepTax")).Text = 
             Convert.ToString(dcTax);
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblRepTotal")).Text = 
              Convert.ToString(dcPriceIncl);
       }                
    }

}
```

### **.aspx code**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repJobCard" runat="server" onitemdatabound="repJobCard_ItemDataBound">
     <td align="center" width="15%">                                   
          <font style="font-size:14px">
               <strong>
                   <asp:Label ID="lblRepPrice" runat="server" Text="">
                   </asp:Label>
               </strong>
          </font>
    </td>
    <td align="center" width="15%">                                   
        <font style="font-size:14px">
            <strong>
               <asp:Label ID="lblRepTax" runat="server" Text="">
               </asp:Label>
            </strong>
        </font>
    </td>
    <td align="center" width="15%">                                   
        <font style="font-size:14px">
              <strong>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblRepTotal" runat="server" Text="">
                  </asp:Label>
              </strong>
        </font>
   </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
protected void Job_History()
{ 
   dsJobCardHistory = objReportManager.Get_JobCard_History(strCustNo, strTranId);
   repJobCard.DataSource = dsJobCardHistory ;
   repJobCard.DataBind();
}

protected void repJobCard_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    string price = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "dcPriceExcl").ToString(); // dcPriceExcl -- or whatever the column names are for your data.
    string tax = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "dcTax").ToString();
    string total = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "dcPriceIncl").ToString();

    Label lblRepPrice = e.Item.FindControl("lblRepPrice") as Label;
    Label lblRepTax = e.Item.FindControl("lblRepTax") as Label;
    Label dcPriceIncl = e.Item.FindControl("dcPriceIncl") as Label;

    lblRepPrice.Text = price;
    lblRepTax.Text = tax;
    dcPriceIncl.Text = total;
}
```

And

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repJobCard" runat="server" onitemdatabound="repJobCard_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        All of your HTML
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Thanks @Stanley, I tried that but it throws a NullReferenceException.